# POST the dropdown selected values to nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I want to post the dropdown value from react to NodeJS.
my react code:

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
export default class Inference extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
       
        model: "",
 
        options: [
          { label: "Cat", value: "cat" },
          { label: "Traffic", value: "traffic" },
          { label: "Dog", value: "dog" },
        ],
      };
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }
  
    handleChange(e) {
     
      this.setState({ model: e.target.value });
      console.log("Model Selected!!");
    }



    handleSubmit(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const { example } = event.target;
      console.log("value", example.value);
    }
  
    componentDidMount() {
        axios
    .post('http://localhost:5000/getmodel', {
  
      model: this.state.model,
   
    })
    .then((res) => {
      // Res.data is the response from your server
      console.log(res.data);
    });

    }
  
    render() {
     
  
      const {  options } = this.state;
  
   
  
      return (
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
  
            <div
              className="col-6"
              style={{
                paddingBottom: "100px",
                paddingTop: "20px",
                alignItems: "center",
              }}
            >
              <label
                className=""
                style={{ paddingTop: "5px", marginTop: "40px" }}
              >
                Model
                <form method="post" action="/getmodel" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                  <select
                    className="custom-select"
                    name="example"
                    value={this.state.model}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    style={{ paddingTop: "5px", marginTop: "10px" }}
                  >
                    <option>--Select--</option>
                    {options.map((option) => (
                      <option
                        value={option.value}
                        onChange={(e) => this.setState({ model: e.target.value })}
                      >
                        {option.label}
                      </option>
                    ))}
                  </select>
  
               
  
                  <button
                    type="submit"
                    class="btn btn-success"
                    style={{ marginTop: "100px" }}
                  >
                    Inference
                  </button>
                </form>
   </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

my nodejs code:

```
  app.post('/getmodel', (req, res) => {
        // Logs course sent from front end
        console.log(req.body.model);
      });
      app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        // Cookies that have not been signed
      console.log('hello: ',req.body)
    
      })
```

please guide me how to post the value to NodeJS so I can get value by req.body.model or something like that. how to get value from react as well I needed
Main motive: i want to get the dropdown selected value from reactjs to  NodeJS. i need some help in react post code and node get(for that post code) kindly help me

Comment: inside the handle submit function call node POST API using axios. `axios.post(URL, {yourPostData})` this will send your data to node server, show as the post API and code in node server if you need perfect answer

Comment: @sojin bro i updated the code kindly check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added the axios in componentDidMount which is wrong, POST should happen when you submit the form. componentDidMount will call after every render it is a a lifecycle method. Please go through react documentation for a better explanation
Try this code POST API will call  when you click the submit button which is "Inference" button

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
export default class Inference extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
       
        model: "",
 
        options: [
          { label: "Cat", value: "cat" },
          { label: "Traffic", value: "traffic" },
          { label: "Dog", value: "dog" },
        ],
      };
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }
  
    handleChange(e) {
     
      this.setState({ model: e.target.value });
      console.log("Model Selected!!");
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      axios.post('http://localhost:5000/getmodel', {
        model: this.state.model,
      })
       .then((res) => {
        // Res.data is the response from your server
        console.log(res.data);
      });
    }
  

  
    render() {
     
  
      const {  options } = this.state;
  
   
  
      return (
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
  
            <div
              className="col-6"
              style={{
                paddingBottom: "100px",
                paddingTop: "20px",
                alignItems: "center",
              }}
            >
              <label
                className=""
                style={{ paddingTop: "5px", marginTop: "40px" }}
              >
                Model
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                  <select
                    className="custom-select"
                    name="example"
                    value={this.state.model}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    style={{ paddingTop: "5px", marginTop: "10px" }}
                  >
                    <option>--Select--</option>
                    {options.map((option) => (
                      <option
                        value={option.value}
                        onChange={(e) => this.setState({ model: e.target.value })}
                      >
                        {option.label}
                      </option>
                    ))}
                  </select>
  
               
  
                  <button
                    type="submit"
                    class="btn btn-success"
                    style={{ marginTop: "100px" }}
                  >
                    Inference
                  </button>
                </form>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state') when i run this code i got this error

Comment: You need to bind this to the form submit, will update my answer

Comment: ok bro please update I'm waiting for it

Comment: I works great bro I'm getting it on my NodeJS now but the problem is i can't able to use it i want to use to querying database this is my code  app.get('/model', (req,res)=>{
  let model = req.body.model;
  let sql ="select * from new_schema.model_list,new_schema.images where model_name=  " + mysql.escape(model)
  db.query(sql,model, (err,results) =>{
   if(err){
    throw err
   }
    console.log(results)
   res.send(results);
  })
 })

Comment: Why you cant use it show me the error getting in node js

Comment: when i run http://localhost:5000/model i get empty array as the result bro

Comment: if you need to check the results and database please post all the node js code and the database in slackbits or similar. we cant say that from assumptions,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238454/discussion-between-karthikeyan-m-and-sojin).

Answer (score 0):

You can use axios to submit the request and include the information in the body of the request. The second parameter of the post method from axios is the body of your request. Here is an example of how to make an axios POST request with data.

```js
axios
    .post('/some_endpoint', {
      dataset: this.state.dataset,
      model: this.state.model,
      course: this.state.course,
    })
    .then((res) => {
      // Res.data is the response from your server
      console.log(res.data);
    });
```

Now on your backend, you can access course through req.body

```js
router.post('/some_endpoint', (req, res) => {
  // Logs course sent from front end
  console.log(req.body.course);
});
```

Comment: @sojin bro i updateed the code with you post code but still i couldn't able to get that data kindly check